# 1/2 Test Methods Passed: first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

Tags: apex, unit-test, email, code-coverage, wrapper-class

I have two test methods doing similar things, but one fails.

Test Code is:

```
@IsTest
private class CaseDocumentListControllerTest {

    static testMethod void testGetContentDocuments() {
        SetupDataClass setup_data = new SetupDataClass();
        System.runAs(setup_data.TestUser) {
            Test.startTest();
            setup_data.insertTestContentDocument();
            setup_data.createLinkWithCase();
            List<CaseDocumentHandler.DocumentMailWrapper> wrappers = CaseDocumentListController.getCaseContentVersions(setup_data.TestCase.Id);
            Test.stopTest();
            System.assertNotEquals(0, wrappers.size(), 'Content versions aren\'t obtained');
        }
    }

// 21/01/20
    static testMethod void testGetEmailMessage() {
        SetupDataClass setup_data = new SetupDataClass();
        System.runAs(setup_data.TestUser) {
            Test.startTest();
            setup_data.insertTestContentDocument();
            setup_data.createLinkWithCase();
//            setup_data.insertTestEmailMessage();
LINE 25   setup_data.createLinkWithEmailMessage();
            List<CaseDocumentHandler.DocumentMailWrapper> wrappers = CaseDocumentListController.getCaseContentVersions(setup_data.TestCase.Id);
            Test.stopTest();
            System.assertNotEquals(0, wrappers.size(), 'Wrappers aren\'t obtsained');
        }
    }


    class SetupDataClass {
        public User TestUser;
        public Case TestCase;
        public ContentDocument TestContentDocument;
        public Case_Document__c TestCaseDocument;
        public List<ContentDocumentLink> TestContentDocumentLinks;
        Public EmailMessage TestEmailMessage;

        public SetupDataClass() {
            TestUser = [SELECT Id, LastName FROM User WHERE LastName = 'CaseDocumentListControllerTest'];
            TestCase = CaseBuilder.getBuilder().save().getRecord();
            TestEmailMessage = EmailMessageBuilder.getBuilder().save().getRecord();
        }

        public void insertTestContentDocument() {
            TestContentDocument = ContentDocumentBuilder.getBuilder().getRecord();
        }

        public void createLinkWithCase() {
            ContentDocumentLinkBuilder.getBuilder()
                    .setLinkedEntityId(TestCase.Id)
                    .setContentDocumentId(TestContentDocument.Id)
                    .save();
        }

//        public void insertTestEmailMessage() {
//            TestEmailMessage = EmailMessageBuilder.getBuilder().getRecord();
//        }

        public void createLinkWithEmailMessage() {
            ContentDocumentLinkBuilder.getBuilder()
                    .setLinkedEntityId(TestEmailMessage.Id)
                    .setContentDocumentId(TestContentDocument.Id)
                    .save();
        }
    }

    @testSetup
    static void setupData() {
        UserTestData.getUserForTest().setProfile(ProfileUtilities.ProfileType.SYSADMIN)
                .setFirstName('CaseDocumentListControllerTest')
                .setLastName('CaseDocumentListControllerTest')
                .save();
    }
}
```

The APEX it is testing is:

```
public with sharing class CaseDocumentHandler {

    public static Set<EmailMessage> Emails = new Set<EmailMessage>();

    public static List<CaseDocumentHandler.DocumentMailWrapper> createEmailDocWrappers(Id case_id) {
        Case target_case = getCase(case_id);
        Map<Id, EmailMessage> emails_by_doc_id = mapEmailsByDocumentId(target_case.CaseNumber, target_case.Claim_Number__c, case_id);
        List<ContentDocumentLink> content_document_links = getContentDocumentLinks(case_id);
        List<CaseDocumentHandler.DocumentMailWrapper> wrappers = new List<CaseDocumentHandler.DocumentMailWrapper>();
        for(ContentVersion version : getContentVersions(getContentDocumentIds(content_document_links)).values()) {
            if(emails_by_doc_id.get(version.ContentDocumentId) == null) {
                DocumentMailWrapper wrapper = new DocumentMailWrapper();
            wrapper.Id = version.Id;
            wrapper.ContentDocumentId = version.ContentDocumentId;
            wrapper.DateOfDocument = version.Date_of_Document__c;
            wrapper.DocumentCategory = version.Document_Category__c;
            wrapper.DocumentType = version.Document_Type__c;
            wrapper.Narrative = version.Narrative__c;
            wrapper.Title = version.Title;
            wrappers.add(wrapper);
            } else {
                Emails.add(emails_by_doc_id.get(version.ContentDocumentId));
            }
        }
        for(EmailMessage email_message : Emails) {
            DocumentMailWrapper wrapper = new DocumentMailWrapper();
            wrapper.EmailId = email_message.Id;
            wrapper.DocumentCategory = email_message.Document_Category__c;
            wrapper.DocumentType = email_message.Document_Type__c;
            wrapper.DateOfDocument = email_message.CreatedDate;
            wrapper.Subject = email_message.Subject;
            wrapper.LastPrinted = email_message.Last_Print_Date_Time__c;    //CCF703 20/01/20
            wrappers.add(wrapper);
        }
        List<String> types = new List<String>();
        if(!wrappers.isEmpty()) {
            for(DocumentMailWrapper wrap : wrappers) {
                if(wrap.DocumentType != null) {
                    types.add(wrap.DocumentType);
                }
            }
        }
        mapAvailability(wrappers, mapAvailabilityByTypes(types));
        wrappers = bubbleSortMailWrappers(wrappers);
        return wrappers;
    }
```

The test method that fails is testGetEmailMessage  as follows:

```
Apex Test Result Detail 
Time Started28/01/2020 15:19
Class  CaseDocumentListControllerTest
Method Name:  testGetEmailMessage
Pass/FailFail
Error MessageSystem.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []
Stack TraceClass.ContentDocumentLinkBuilder.Builder.save: line 33, column 1
Class.CaseDocumentListControllerTest.SetupDataClass.createLinkWithEmailMessage: line 66, column 1
Class.CaseDocumentListControllerTest.testGetEmailMessage: line 25, column 1
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You have `insertTestEmailMessage()` commented out. As written, there is no value in `TestEmailMessage`, so its `Id` is `null`. Are you running the code in this state?

Comment: Hi David  Thanks for your reply.  I had tried both. Same result when not commented out. Desmond

Comment: I have since added.....  setCase(TestCase.Id) to  TestEmailMessage = EmailMessageBuilder.getBuilder().setCase(TestCase.Id).save().getRecord(); and have made progress.. now get new Error Message System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, Invalid sharing type I: [ShareType]
Stack Trace Class.ContentDocumentLinkBuilder.Builder.save: line 33, column 1
Class.CaseDocumentListControllerTest.SetupDataClass.createLinkWithEmailMessage: line 65, column 1
Class.CaseDocumentListControllerTest.testGetEmailMessage: line 25, column 1